# Android - How to get the time of created button

Tags: java, android, c++

Is there any function in Android, that can return time, when the `Button` was created (displayed) in layout. I am using now something like that, but I don't know, how realistic time it returns.

`frameLay.addView(okButton,layoutParams);
Date date1 = new Date();
setTimeCreate(date1.getTime());`

Maybe there are some functions in C/C++, which I can use.

PS: Sorry for my English, I am not native english speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
System.currentTimeMillis() - returns current time in milliseconds.
```

Comment: Do not mention it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level of accuracy required, you could use, either of these two:

```
System.nanoTime()

System.currentTimeMillis()
```